# Shopify gem create products from database script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I'm using the shopify app gem (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) to create an embedded app in my client's shopify site. I'm trying to iterate through one of our db's tables and create a new product in shopify for each row.

```
    class ProductController < ApplicationController
around_filter :shopify_session
layout 'embedded_app'
def new
        @parts = Part.all
        @parts.each do |part|
            @product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
            @product.title = part.style_name
            @product.sku = part.sku
            @product.upc = part.upc
            @product.weight = part.weight
            @product.product_type = "Part"
            @product.vendor = part.vendor
            @product.tags = "part"
            @product.save
        end
end
end
```

I am working locally and when I hit product new action I get this error: "Failed. Response code = 403. Response message = Forbidden."

Answer (score 2):

So, "Missing site URI" means you did not activate a session with the Shopify API server before asking it to persist data. You need to get a token from the API first, using the domain name and the token from the shop into which you're loading the products.

I need more information in order to help you more, if needed.

Comment: I realized I was missing the line "around_filter :shopify_session" in the class to access the session. But now I am getting this error: "Failed. Response code = 403. Response message = Forbidden."

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a 403 because I had to visit /login first to create a new sessions by entering my shop's domain.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to remove the Appplication Controller and add like this 
ProductController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
By this you will directly get access to the sessions